# how is the equality between objects done?

Tags: java, types

if we create 3 variables of int type using different declaration statements, for instance,

```
Integer i = 10; 
Integer j = new Integer(10); 
int k = 10;
```

and we compare them for equality, we get `i == k`  and `j == k` but not `i==j`.

what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 5):

Since `i` has type `Integer` and `k` has type `int`, the expression `i == k` triggers [*unboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html): it is equivalent to `i.intValue() == k` (even to the point that it would raise a `NullPointerException` if `i` were null). Similarly for `j == k`. But since `i` and `j` both have type `Integer`, no autounboxing is performed, so `i == j` simply checks to see if they are the same object — the same instance of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `k` is primitive and when you compare it with others you only compare its integer value.But the other two are objects. When you compare them with `==` operator you only check if they are the same object or not.

You should use `equals()` method to compare `Integer` objects.The following will return `true` in your program.

```
i.equals(j);
```